# Properly using Foreign Keys in the Entity Framework to display Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm creating the simplest Forum in the world and its tables are setup like this:

```
Users | Id, Name  
Posts | Id, Content, PosterId (FK to Users(Id))
```

The information would be displayed like this:

```
[Poster Name] | [Post content]    | Post #1
[Poster Name] | [Post content]    | Post #2
```

What I read is that, to deal with the FK, my model class for `Posts` should be setup like this:

```
public class PostModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Poster")]
    public string PosterId { get; set; }
    public User Poster { get; set; }
}
```

This may be a silly question but I'm somewhat confused about this. Since Users:Posts is 1:N, if a post is made by the same user, will I be creating multiple copies of the same `User` object? If I have a `ForumEntity` that encompasses `DbSet`s of `Users` and `Posts`, should I load in all the users, then query from it to get a reference to the proper user for every post (eg. delete the `Poster` property from `PostModel`)? What is the correct way to write and use my model class?

Comment: First off, using "Poster" and "PosterId" in your Post model to refer to a User is confusing. There are lots of ways to set the child (User). You can fetch it from the database and do a Post.User = context.Users.Find(id) or you can just set the FK Post.UserId = id.

Comment: Read some basics on this subject: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx